# Can someone please centralise the [dynamics-business-central] and [microsoft-dynamics-business-central] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [dynamics-business-central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-business-central) and [microsoft-dynamics-business-central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-business-central) are absolute synonyms (There isn't a non-Microsoft Dynamics Business Central) and both tags are active,  I don't have enough points to suggest a synonym.

Suggest Dynamics-Business-Central should be the 'main' tag it's slightly more popular (and shorter!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added [microsoft-dynamics-business-central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-business-central) as a synonym for [dynamics-business-central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-business-central), as requested. Most of the questions had both the tags and all of them were referring to Microsoft's Dynamic Business Central itself. They're now synonyms, that is:

[microsoft-dynamics-business-central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-business-central) (× 52) → [dynamics-business-central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-business-central) (× 88)

I'll merge them after a few days, just to make sure that there are no issues with it. The next step is to write a nice tag wiki for it, as I rolled back the current excerpt due to plagiarism.